# SwiftUI - using ForEach with a Binding array that does not conform to identifiable / hashable

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, hashable, identifiable

I have the a codable object as follows:

```
struct IncidentResponse: Codable {
    let incident: IncidentDetails?
}

struct IncidentDetails: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String?
    let reason: IncidentReasonResponse?
    let message: String?
    let startedAt: String?
    let endedAt: String?
}

struct IncidentReasonResponse: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String?
    let code: String?
    let inOp: Bool?
}
```

Here is an example of an incident response when called from the API:

```
{
  "incident": {
    "id": "610aebad8c719475517e9736",
    "user": null,
    "reason": {
      "name": "No aircraft",
      "code": "no-aircraft",
      "inOp": true
    },
    "message": "test this",
    "startedAt": "2021-08-04T19:34:05+0000",
    "endedAt": null
  }
}
```

In SwiftUI, I am trying to display a list of these. So I have an array of these IncidentResponse objects named existingIncidents and then the following:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        Section(header: Text("Existing incidents")) {
            if let existingIncidents = self.existingIncidents {
                ForEach(existingIncidents) { incident in
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack {
                            Image.General.incident
                                .foregroundColor(Constants.iconColor)
                            Text(incident.incident?.reason?.name ?? "")
                                .foregroundColor(Constants.textColor)
                                .bold()
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        HStack {
                            Image.General.clock
                                .foregroundColor(Constants.iconColor)
                            Text(incident.incident?.startedAt ?? "No date")
                                .foregroundColor(Constants.textColor)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        HStack {
                            Image.General.message
                                .foregroundColor(Constants.iconColor)
                            Text(incident.incident?.message ?? "No message")
                                .foregroundColor(Constants.textColor)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

However, I am unable to use existingIncidents as it is as it does not conform to Identifiable or Hashable (so I can't use the id: /.self workaround) ...

How can I get around this?

I tried to add a UUID into IncidentResponse like this:

```
struct IncidentResponse: Codable {
    let incident: IncidentDetails?
    var id = UUID().uuidString
}
```

However, this is then stopping the object from decoding properly from the API.

Comment: Are you positive that `IncidentDetails` has an *Optional* `id` property, or is it always present?

Comment: I can probably make this non optional

Comment: Okay -- similarly, is `IncidentDetails?` really optional at the top level?

Comment: Again, no - I've gone OTT on the optionals to be fair

Comment: Since a IncidentResponse have exactly one IncidentDetails why not skip this irrelevant outer type and map your array to an array of IncidentDetails that already has an id property and can easily be made to conform to Identifiable

Comment: Thanks for this - but as the API response is wrapped in incident {} do I not require this for decoding purposes?

Comment: @DevB1 you need it for decoding, but then you can ditch it later (see the last part of my answer)

Comment: Ah right yes, gotcha. Yeah that's not a bad call, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1:

Give your `IncidentResponse` an ID and then tell it to not try to decode the value:

```
struct IncidentResponse: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let incident: IncidentDetails?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case incident
    }
}
```

### Option 2:

Make `incident` and `id` non-optional and then use this to get the id:

```
ForEach(existingIncidents, id: \.incident.id) { incident in
```

---

I'll also note that `IncidentResponse` seems to be a somewhat meaningless wrapper at this point. When you do your decoding and store the values to `existingIncidents` (which you haven't shown), you could probably store them just as `[IncidentDetails]` instead. In that case, you just have to make the `id` property non-optional on `IncidentDetails` and declare it as `Identifiable`. For example:

```
struct IncidentDetails: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let reason: IncidentReasonResponse?
    let message: String?
    let startedAt: String?
    let endedAt: String?
}

//....

let existingIncidentsWrappers : [IncidentResponse] = //...
let existingIncidents : [IncidentDetails] = existingIncidentsWrappers.compactMap { $0.incident }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - I've implemented option number one and this works perfectly. Thanks again :)

Comment: Sure. If it was helpful, please consider upvoting.